# idea compile gradle web project error not include webapp directory

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm new gradle web project and config web.xml in `WEB-INF` directory

using tomcat deploy success and open `localhost:8080 or localhost:8080/index.jspd` found 404 error

this is compile and directory files

[image]

I'm open terminal found 8080 port is opened

[image]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189112 may be the case.